# Sendgrid Codeigniter setting a category

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

Alright so I am trying to set a category using Sendgrid & Codeigniter. I am unable to use their STMP api so I have to do it manually but how?

This is my current code

```
$body = $this->load->view('mail_templates/users/SG_register_confirmation',$data, true);
$this->email->from($this->config->item('contact_email'), "Welcome!");
$this->email->to($this->config->item('to'));
$this->email->cc($this->config->item('cc'));
$this->email->subject($this->config->item('test_subject'));
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->message($body);
$this->email->send();
```

Now the email works perfectly, but I cant seem to find a way to set its category old fashioned way...

Comment: How would you set a category using Sendgrid otherwise?

Comment: @NeilPatrao here you can see how its usually done
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html

Comment: Well, that's a long page, you need to include relevant parts of code in your question that could be helpful to others answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html), set your category using:

```
$json_string = array(

    'to' => array(
        'example1@sendgrid.com', 'example2@sendgrid.com'
    ),
    'category' => 'test_category'
);
```

Then set the custom category header using the `set_header` method

```
$this->email->set_header('x-smtpapi', json_encode($json_string));
```

See [this page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) for the full list of methods supported by the Codeigniter `Email` library.

You could also use `SMTP` by setting Email Preferences. For eg.:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'smtp_user';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'smtp_pass';

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Hmm that seems okay, but do I have to set all data using header or I can only go with "to" and for example "category"

Comment: For data like "to", "from" and others supported by the library, you can use the corresponding methods. For everything else, you need to use `set_header` to set a custom header.